# TypeError: Cannot read property 'emoji' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

I am trying to make emoji reaction for my discord bot , everything is okay until I click "❌" emoji but when i click "❌" emoji i am getting this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'emoji' of undefined`

and the error shows this line : `if (reaction.emoji.name === '❌')`

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const ayarlar = require("../ayarlar.json");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

    let gonderenKisi = message.author;
    let mesaj = args.slice(0).join(" ");
    if(!mesaj) return message.reply("**➤ Mesaj Atabilmek İçin Bir Mesaj Yazmalısın!**").then(message => {
        message.delete({ timeout: 5000 });
    });
  
  const filter = (reaction, user) => {
            return ['❌'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;
        };
  
    const sEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setDescription(`➤ ` + mesaj)
        .setAuthor(`➤ Yeni Bir Fotoğraf Paylaşıldı !`)
        .setThumbnail(message.guild.iconURL())
        .setColor('RANDOM')
        .setFooter(`➤ Fotoğraf Atan: ${message.author.username}`, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
        .setTimestamp(message.createdAt)
    message.delete();
    message.channel.send(sEmbed).then(e => 
      e.react("❤️")).then(e =>
      e.message.react("❌")).catch(e => {

        console.error('Emojiler De Sorun Var.');
    });

message.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1 })
    .then(collected => {
  
     const reaction = collected.first();
  
     if (reaction.emoji.name === '❌') {

            collected.on('collect', () => {
              
                message.delete();

                var s2Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()

                .setTitle(`${message.author.username} Mesajın Silindi.`)

                .setColor('RANDOM')

                .setDescription(`Mesajı Silen : ${message.author.username}`, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
                
                message.channel.send(s2Embed)
            });
        }
   

   }).catch(e => {
  console.error(e)
})
};


module.exports.config = {
    name: 'instagram',
    aliases: ['i']
}
```

Comment: This ` collected.first()` returns undefined for you. You need to first validate that it's returning your desired object, then `reaction` will have the `emoji` property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual cause of the error is this line:

```
const reaction = collected.first();
```

Here the value of reaction is **undefined** so you are getting the error.You are trying to read the emoji property of an undefined value.You can change the condition to:

```
if (reaction && reaction.emoji && reaction.emoji.name){
////logic
}
```

Also I can see there is some issue in the discord version probably which is giving you an undefined value. Check this thread it may help you.

> https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/3868